# RethinkDB - is there a better way of doing this non-atomic update on a nested array?

Tags: arrays, nested, rethinkdb

I have two tables in a RethinkDB database - "leagues" and "players", with document structure as follows:

player

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Bob",
  email: "bob@bob.com"
}
```

league

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "L1",
  standings: [{
    "player_id": 1,
    "position": 1
  },{
    "player_id": 2,
    "position": 2
  }]
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is when a player is deleted, there is an obviously simple ReQL query to remove the player:

```
r.table("players").get(1).delete().run(conn, callback);
```

But I also need to remove that player from any leagues that they are playing in, and then update the positions of all other players in that league so they become sequential again.

This is the query I have to remove a player with id "2":

```
r.table("leagues").getAll(2, { index: "player_id" }).update({
  standings: r.row("standings").filter(function(standing) {
    return standing("player_id").ne(2)
  }).map(function(standing) {
    return r.branch (
      standing("position").gt(
        r.table("leagues").getAll(2, { index: "player_id" }).nth(0)("standings").filter(function(s) {
            return s("player_id").eq(2)
            }).nth(0)("position")
      ),
      standing.merge({ position: standing("position").sub(1) }),
      standing
    )
  })
}, {
  nonAtomic: true 
})
```

And this is working, it removes the deleted player, and then shuffles the positions of the remaining players to fill the gap and become sequential again.

My question is, is there a better way? One where I don't have to specify the query as nonAtomic? I can only think that I'd need to do a number of separate queries first, to find the position of the player I want to remove, so that can be passed in as a variable rather than a subquery as I believe it's that part that is making this nonAtomic.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the standings always match the position in the array?

If so, you could write it like this:

```
r.table('leagues').getAll(2, {index: 'player_id'}).update(function(row) {
  return {
    standings: row('standings').filter(function (standing) {
      return standing('player_id').ne(2);
    }.map(r.range(), function(standing, index) {
      return standing.merge({position: index.add(1)});
    })
  };
});
```

If not, you could write it like this:

```
r.table('leagues').getAll(2, {index: 'player_id'}).update(function(row) {
  return row('standings').filter(function (standing) {
    return standing('player_id').eq(2);
  }).nth(0)('position').do(function(pos) {
    return {
      standings: row('standings').filter(function (standing) {
        return standing('player_id').ne(2);
      }).map(function(standing) {
        return r.branch(
          standing('position').gt(pos),
          standing.merge({position: standing('position').sub(1)}),
          standing);
      })
    };
  });
});
```

{
        standings: row('standings').filter(function (standing) {
          return standing('player_id').ne(2)
        }.map(r.range(), function(standing, index) {
          return standing.merge({position: index.add(1)});
        })
      };
    })

Comment: Brilliant thanks, the second query worked a treat. The first one threw an error: Expected type DATUM but found SEQUENCE